# How to run custom wp-cli commands using node-wp-cli?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, wp-cli

I am using [node-wp-cli](https://github.com/gtg092x/node-wp-cli) to run WP-cli commands from Node.js. All inbuilt WP-cli commands works perfectly but I stuck while trying to run my custom WP-cli commands.

Is there a way to to run my custom WP-Cli commands `wp MyRegisteredCommand SubCommand` from node-wp-cli? like:

```
WP.MyRegisteredCommand.SubCommand(function(err,res){ //get response
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy, but requires some tweaking...

Node wp-cli uses `wp cli cmd-dump` to identify the available commands, but this command runs before the WordPress is loaded, so it will recognize only the in-built commands.

The tweak in short:

- See `WP.js`, line `schema(function(err,schema){...`. You need to know the structure of `schema`, so just run some in-built command and put a breakpoint here.
- Implement the schema for your commands, following the schema structure above. It will look something like this:

  `my_commands.js`:

  ```
  var schema = {
      mycmd: {
          mysubcmd: {
              args: [ {
                  arg: 'arg1',
                  required: true,
                  type: 'args'
              } ],
              endpoint: true,
              options: {
                  opt1: {
                      required: true,
                      type: 'param'
                  },
                  flag1: {
                      required: false,
                      type: 'flag'
                  },
              }
          },
          use: 'wp mycmd mysubcmd'
      }
  }

  module.exports.schema = schema;
  ```
- Modify `WP.js`:

  ```
  var mySchema = require('my_commands.js').schema;

  ...

  schema(function(err,schema){

      schema = _.merge(schema, mySchema); // this line added

      var toMerge = function mapSchema(schema){
  ```